# Getting a point from a vector, length and angle

Tags: c#, logic, unity-game-engine

Using the diagram below, if we know the vectors 'point A' and 'point B' as well as side lengths a,b,c. Is it possible to get the exact vectors for points D & C?

[image: Figure 1]

My current code to generate this cube's vertices, however, this only works if sides a and b are of equal length.

```
void GenTriangleC() {
    triC [0] = pointB;
    triC [1] = pointA;
    triC [2] = new Vector3 (pointA.x + sideB, pointA.y + sideA, 0); 
    triC [3] = triC [0];
    triC [4] = triC [2];
    triC [5] = new Vector3 (pointB.x + sideB, pointB.y + sideA);
}
```

Comment: Uh, this is strictly a math problem, right? Unless you tried to implement it in code and share your unsuccessful attempt, unfortunately it's off-topic for Stack Overflow. Have you considered https://math.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Made that realization after I answered the question.

Comment: Sorry, I have added the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the diagram, it looks you can do this:

`D.x = A.x + a`

`D.y = A.y + b`

`C.x = B.x + a`

`C.y = B.y + b`

Below is a diagram illustrating the math:

[image: square within a square][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgUKn.png)

I'm visualizing this by drawing the same triangle (a,b,c) around the square with side c. However, since we're simply dealing with diagrams and not code, perhaps this a better problem for math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have tried implementing your solution, however, it only seems to function correctly if sides a and b are of equal lengths.

Comment: My first answer was wrong and had a and b in the wrong spots. Can you try again?